# ByteBuffer api giving wrong integer values

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I am using ByteBuffer APIs to convert an object into bytes. The object's class is as follows

```
public class Obj{
int a; // size 1 byte
int b; // size 4 bytes
int c; // size 4 bytes
}
```

Using ByteBuffer API, I have allocated an object

```
ByteBuffer bbf = ByteBuffer.allocate(9);
bbf.put((byte) this.getA());
bbf.putInt(this.getB());
bbf.putInt(this.getC());
byte[] msg = bbf.array();
```

I set the value of B as 100 but when I convert the byte array from offset 1 till length 4, I get a different integer value.
Any idea where is the problem?
thanks!

Comment: The offsets are a:0, b:1, c:5.  Do you need the value to be big endian or little endian?

Comment: i set the byte order to Little Endian. But the problem is still there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works as it should, and if you indeed select bytes with index 1,2,3,4 they will yield the value 100:

```
ByteBuffer bbf = ByteBuffer.allocate(9);
bbf.put((byte) 10);
bbf.putInt(100);
bbf.putInt(55);
byte[] msg = bbf.array();

byte[] from4to8 = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 1, 5);

ByteBuffer buf2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(from4to8);
System.out.println(buf2.getInt());             // Prints 100
```

---

Some notes:

- Keep in mind that the endian may differ from system to system (so check the endian on both hosts if this is part of a protocol)
- The array you get from the `bbf.array()` call is a *backing array*, i.e.:

  > *Modifications to this buffer's content will cause the returned array's content to be modified, and vice versa.*

Comment: tried your code, with byte order as LittleEndian. I get the printed value as 1677721600

Comment: That's the value you get if you take bytes 0,1,2,3, instead of 1,2,3,4. (I.e. if you change from 1,5 to 0,4 in the example in my answer).

Comment: By the second note do you mean I have to convert each instance variable separately using different ByteBuffer object? If not please explain in detail

Comment: set also the byte order of buf2 to little endian

Comment: It simply says that you shouldn't use `msg` as an array containing a *copy* of the content of the `bbf`, it *is* the content of the `bbf`. If you have some lines in between, changing `bbf` the content of `msg` will change at the same time.

Comment: After using array() i am not making any changes to msg or bbf. And I am still getting wrong value

Comment: private static int MakeInt(byte[] msg, int offset, int len)
 {
  int intValue = 0;
  for (int ctr = offset; ctr < len + offset; ctr++)
  {
   intValue += (msg[ctr] & 0xff) << (8 * (len - 1 - ctr));
  }
  return intValue;
 }

I am using the above function to output the value. Anything wrong in this?

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Implement it like `return ByteBuffer.wrap(msg, offset, len).getInt();`

Comment: (Or replace your strange looking `+=` line with just `intValue = (intValue << 8) | msg[i];`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, `B` is at offset 1

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Correction made.